# @Html.DropDownListFor, how to add customized field in the option tags?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
                        model => model.data, 
                        new SelectList(Model.data, "Value", "Text"), 
                        ""
                    )
```

How to make it look like

```
<option value="131" value2="a">text1</option>
<option value="132" value2="c">text2</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with the [DropDownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor.aspx) helper. You can check it in the [source-code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70574#288014) (look for the `ListItemToOption` method).
You can write your own helper which generates for you the additional attributes or you can try to add them on client side with [jQuery attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).